# Detect Nvidia's NVC++ (not NVCC) compiler and compiler version

Tags: c++, linux, nvidia, hpc

I am using Nvidia's HPC compiler `nvc++`.

**Is there a way to detect that the program is being compile with this specific compiler and the version?**

I couldn't find anything in the manual https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/index.html.

Another Nvidia-related compiler `nvcc` has these macros

```
__NVCC__
    Defined when compiling C/C++/CUDA source files.
__CUDACC__
    Defined when compiling CUDA source files.
__CUDACC_RDC__
    Defined when compiling CUDA source files in relocatable device code mode (see NVCC Options for Separate Compilation). 
__CUDACC_EWP__
    Defined when compiling CUDA source files in extensible whole program mode (see Options for Specifying Behavior of Compiler/Linker). 
__CUDACC_DEBUG__
    Defined when compiling CUDA source files in the device-debug mode (see Options for Specifying Behavior of Compiler/Linker). 
__CUDACC_RELAXED_CONSTEXPR__
    Defined when the --expt-relaxed-constexpr flag is specified on the command line. Refer to CUDA C++ Programming Guide for more details. 
__CUDACC_EXTENDED_LAMBDA__
    Defined when the --expt-extended-lambda or --extended-lambda flag is specified on the command line. Refer to CUDA C++ Programming Guide for more details. 
__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__
    Defined with the major version number of nvcc. 
__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__
    Defined with the minor version number of nvcc. 
__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__
    Defined with the build version number of nvcc. 
__NVCC_DIAG_PRAGMA_SUPPORT__
    Defined when the CUDA frontend compiler supports diagnostic control with the nv_diag_suppress, nv_diag_error, nv_diag_warning, nv_diag_default, nv_diag_once, nv_diagnostic pragmas.
```

but I couldn't find the equivalent for `nvc++`.
The `strings` command didn't show any good candidate for macro names.

```
$ strings /opt/nvidia/hpc_sdk/Linux_x86_64/22.1/compilers/bin/nvc++ | grep D
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__NVCOMPILER` `__NVCOMPILER_MAJOR__` `__NVCOMPILER_MINOR__`

Found them accidentally in a random third-party library https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/core.h

```
#ifdef __NVCOMPILER
#  define FMT_NVCOMPILER_VERSION \
    (__NVCOMPILER_MAJOR__ * 100 + __NVCOMPILER_MINOR__)
#else
#  define FMT_NVCOMPILER_VERSION 0
#endif
```